# При добавление кнопки назад вылетает ошибка

Tags: android, android-toolbar, toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:id="@+id/HonorsActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HonorsActivity">


<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="413dp"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="675dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageMenu1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"

    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"

    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_book"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar"
    app:tint="@color/white" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Toolbar.setNavigationIcon(int)' on a null object reference
at com.example.khrenovskayastudfarm.HonorsActivity.onCreate(HonorsActivity.java:36)

```
public class HonorsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_honors);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_book);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: Вы объявили переменную но не проинициадизировади еë.

Comment: подскажите что нужно сделать на примере?

Comment: Надо написать `toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` после `setContentView(R.layout.activity_honors);`

Comment: приложение вылетает, ругается как раз таки на toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

Comment: теперь ругается, скорее всего, потому что у вас используется уже тема приложения с тулбаром. заменить ее. и прикладываете всегда саму ошибку.

Comment: Переформулировал вопрос

Comment: @Крафт, вы не переформулировали вопрос, а заменили старый вопрос на полностью новый. Так не следует делать - один вопрос - один ответ. Задайте новый вопрос и верните текст как было - это можно в истории правок вопроса выбрать откат к нужной версии. Наверное вопрос с тулбаром у вас решился, а новая проблема у вас с дровером - там в одну строку решение, но надо новый вопрос задать.

Comment: как все сложно)) старую версию уже  не верну...задавать вопрос заново?

Comment: Я откатил) Да, надо новый вопрос. Ну или просто добавьте android:gravity="start" Той вьюхе в разметке что должна стать выдвигающимся меню

Comment: Все равно ошибка (( сделаю новый вопрос